# Extract part of a cell's text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, string-manipulation

I have text values in 10's of thousands of cells. I want to pull off the "prefix" and put it in a separate column. We have a delimiter, guaranteed, of a hyphen with spaces around it to help pick off the prefix. The problem is that the hyphen might also appear elsewhere in the same cell's text.

Using this formula:   =LEFT(I85,LEN(I85)-SEARCH("-",I85,1))
yields more than I want in those cases. See problem example below.

Example of problem:
Col A   ===============> yields Col B

ABC - Sample Name - blah blah blah =====> ABC - Sample Name

BUT, I only want 'ABC' in Col B, not 'ABC - Sample Name'.

Many thanks in advance!
Margaret

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Text To Columns command on the Data menu to put each record in a separate column using the hyphen as the delimiter.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261